# not allowed to load local resource image file:///C:/uploads/images

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database

I'm trying to get a photo URL but I get a 'no allowed' error message.

The URL comes like `C:\\upload\images`, but on chrome it looks like like `C://upload/images`.

How can I solve this problem?

```
   @foreach (Product pro in Model.Products)
    {
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
            <div class="single-product">`enter code here`
                <a href="/Product/Detay/@pro.Id"><img class="img-fluid" src="@pro.ThumpNailPicture" alt=""></a>
                <div class="product-details">
                    <h6>
                        <a href="/Product/Detay/@pro.Id">@pro.Name</a>
                    </h6>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are asking, but in general it is best to serve content over HTTP rather than directly from local disk. This can be done either via the wwwroot folder or a dedicated static content server.